# jquery dialog box draggable feature not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript file which contains the following jquery code for popup dialog div tag with textarea and a button in it. I want to make this popup draggable, however even after using draggable:true feature and also enabling the draggable feature true using the parent div tag it is not working..... Any suggestion?

```
 $(".showDialog").click(__bind(function() {

    var element, dialogId, textareaHtml;

    dialogId = "" + this.namespace + "dialog";
    textareaHtml = "<textarea style=\"width: 564px; height: 242px;\" id=\"textareadialog\" name=\"description_dialog_textarea\">" + ($("#description").val()) + "</textarea><input readonly type=\"text\" class=\"counter\" name=\"counter\" size=\"4\" maxlength=\"4\" value=\"4000\">;
    $("<div id=\"" + dialogId + "\>").html(textareaHtml).dialog({
      autoOpen: true,
      title: "Description",
      modal: true,
      width: 625,
      height: 360,
      draggable: true,
      buttons: {
        save: __bind(function() {
          var val;
          val = $("#textareadialog").val();
          $("#description").val(val);
          $("#description_fake").html(val);
          $("#description_fake").attr("title", val);
          $('#' + dialogId).dialog("close");
          $('#' + dialogId).remove();
          this.makeDescriptionCluetips();
          return this.update();
        }, this)
      },
      close: function() {
        return $('#' + dialogId).remove();
      }
    });
```

Comment: You are missing a quote at the end of the `textareaHtml ` definition. Is it just a typo?

Answer (score 0):

it is always better to enclose `'` Single quote while you have an string with `"` double quote, its an hack to avoid mistakes.

Change the line

```
textareaHtml = "<textarea style=\"width: 564px; height: 242px;\" id=\"textareadialog\" name=\"description_dialog_textarea\">" + ($("#description").val()) + "</textarea><input readonly type=\"text\" class=\"counter\" name=\"counter\" size=\"4\" maxlength=\"4\" value=\"4000\">;
$("<div id=\"" + dialogId + "\>").html(textareaHtml).dialog({
```

to

```
textareaHtml = '<textarea style="width: 564px; height: 242px;" id="textareadialog" name="description_dialog_textarea">'+$("#description").val()+'</textarea><input readonly type="text" class="counter" name="counter" size="4" maxlength="4" value="4000">';
$('<div id="'+dialogId+'">').html(textareaHtml).dialog({
```

And also, if you say, you are targeting id, then directly use `$("#"+dialogId)` instead of `$('<div id="'+dialogId+'">')`

Comment: after changing it the code becomes completely unresponsive. the popup itself doesn't work.. No error in the console either..

Comment: add a fiddle please, because cannot make out like this. because whatever i have added in my reply, is only change of single quotes to double quotes. so this may not effect to any sort of other error.